# How do i link a compiler to an editor

Tags: java, atom-editor

So i have tried to find an answer but didn't manage to do it yet.  What I'm trying to do is to write a Java code for example in Atom editor, and compile it on Atom itself, without the need of an integrated development environment.  Same goes with adding classes to a project.

Is that possible?

Comment: so, to avoid using an IDE, you instead want to take a text editor, and make it into... an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That is how they wrote the first Integrated Development Environments. Although the compilation step is typically performed externally from the editor, if the editor can execute external programs then you can "integrate" compilation. Adding "classes" is a little more involved, in that it requires your "editor" to understand the packaging and structure of the files composing the classes - at that point you have an integrated development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible with atom package `build`. To install the package `Edit-->Preferences-->Install` and type `build` and hit Enter. Then you should configure your custom build command as mentioned in [official package website](https://atom.io/packages/build). You  may just fill cmd: javac in yml file for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a package that will compile. Atom is a hackable text editor but not really an IDE as you pointed out. That said there are a lot of packages for compiling and for working with java.

You can look at [Build Tools Package](https://atom.io/packages/build-tools) for compiling. It looks like it will work for Java but there are many compilers in the package list.

I would search on their package site for the keyword "Java" to see what java packages you might want to use. Then do another search for "Compile" to see what compiler you might want to use if the build tool above doesn't work for you. You can search atom packages at https://atom.io/packages.